# How do I read binary C++ protobuf data using Python protobuf?

Tags: c++, python, protocol-buffers

The Python version of Google protobuf gives us only:

```
SerializeAsString()
```

Where as the C++ version gives us both:

```
SerializeToArray(...)
SerializeAsString()
```

We're writing to our C++ file in binary format, and we'd like to keep it this way. That said, is there a way of reading the binary data into Python and parsing it as if it were a string?

<s>Is this the correct way of doing it?</s>

```
binary = get_binary_data()
binary_size = get_binary_size()

string = None
for i in range(len(binary_size)):
   string += i

message = new MyMessage()
message.ParseFromString(string)
```

### Update:

Here's a new example, and a problem:

```
message_length = 512

file = open('foobars.bin', 'rb')

eof = False
while not eof:

    data = file.read(message_length)
    eof = not data

    if not eof:
        foo_bar = FooBar()
        foo_bar.ParseFromString(data)
```

When we get to the `foo_bar.ParseFromString(data)` line, I get this error:

```
Exception Type: DecodeError
Exception Value: Too many bytes when decoding varint.
```

### Update 2:

It turns out, that the padding on the binary data was throwing protobuf off; too many bytes were being sent in, as the message suggests (in this case it was referring to the padding).

This padding comes from using the C++ protobuf function, `SerializeToArray` on a fixed-length buffer. To eliminate this, I have used this temproary code:

```
message_length = 512

file = open('foobars.bin', 'rb')

eof = False
while not eof:

    data = file.read(message_length)
    eof = not data

    string = ''
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        byte = data[i]
        if byte != '\xcc': # yuck!
            string += data[i]

    if not eof:
        foo_bar = FooBar()
        foo_bar.ParseFromString(string)
```

There is a design flaw here I think. I will re-implement my C++ code so that it writes variable length arrays to the binary file. As advised by the protobuf documentation, I will prefix each message with it's binary size so that I know how much to read when I'm opening the file with Python.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do with your loop, but you're going to raise a `TypeError` with that.  You assign `None` to the name `string`, and then attempt to add a series of `int`s to it.  

In python, a string is a sequence of bytes, so any binary data should be safe in a string.  Can you explain more clearly what `SerializeAsString` is doing wrong with your data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert with Python, but you can pass the result of a `file.read()` operation into `message.ParseFromString(...)` without having to build a new string type or anything.

Answer (score 4):

Python strings can contain any character, i.e. they are capable of holding "binary" data directly. There should be no need to convert from string to "binary".

Comment: This is not true anymore for Python 3.